# Duplicate class android.support.v4.All kind

Tags: android

> Duplicate class
>   android.support.v4.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
>   found in modules classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0) and classes.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0)

and so on so many errors like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sakhi.live_scoure"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation files('libs/awais.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation project(':dBPullToRefresh')

}
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'
```

Comment: Same problem . its not working

Comment: Try to add this `    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` and run again.

Answer (score 0):

you are using older GCM Service, you can resolve by replace this line 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1' To 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'

by replacing this line you can resolve but i will suggest you to upgrade GCM to FCM (firebase messaging) because GCM is now shutdown his services.